# Access Query in VB 2010

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have the following select query that I need to convert to a delete query to remove duplicates.

Trouble is I cannot seem to get the delete part to work. In the Query builder this selects the records I need to delete.

```
SELECT [Field1], [Field2], [Field3], [Field4], COUNT([Field4]) AS CountOfDuplicates
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY [Field1], [Field2], [Field3],[Field4]
HAVING (COUNT([Field4])>1)
```

Changing SELECT to DELETE causes an error 'Missing FROM Clause'

Thanks

Comment: you can SELECT fields or columns, but you DELETE rows and you CANNOT delete the COUNT which does not exist in the db.  To "delete" a field, use an UPDATE query to set those columns to some default value like 0 or `String.Empty` depending on the Type and whats allowed

Comment: This selects all rows having duplicates. If you delete them, they will not be duplicated – that’s what you want – but they will also completely disappear from the table, which I doubt is what you want. One record from each duplicate group should remain in the table, am I right?

Comment: Yes, One record should remain from the records with duplicate fields.

Comment: So If any type and anything is allowed how would you do it?

Answer (score 0):

Not what I wanted to do originally but I settled for this option. Created another table to remove duplicates by SELECT * INTO table FROM table GROUP BY *

This removes rows that are duplicates.

```
SELECT [Field1], [Field2], [Field3], [Field4]
INTO tempTable
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY [Field1], [Field2], [Field3],[Field4];


DELETE * FROM MyTable;

INSERT INTO MyTable SELECT tempTable.* FROM tempTable;
```